# Dealing with missing values in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am handling a SAS dataset with little observations and I need to put on relation a variable with its lag.

By doing this, I lose a record resulting in a missing values.

Do some of you know how SAS Base handles such items in the procedures as PROC REG or PROC CORR?

Thanks you all in advance.

Comment: Why not test it yourself? Take a small sample dataset, insert some missing values and see how the output changes.

Comment: Hi @user667489! Because the mine one is a general question, not on a specific PROC. The question is about how SAS handles missing values generally.

Comment: You will need to refer to the documentation for each proc that you are interested in. This is a very broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on what exactly you're doing. Based on your references to PROC REG and CORR - it excludes the missing values - listwise. This means if any value is missing in a row that is being used or referenced in the PROC it will be excluded.

http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p175x77t7k6kggn1io94yedqagl3.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

PROC CORR has several options that allow you to specify how it handles the missing values. The NOMISS option tells SAS to use only complete cases.

https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/01/13/missing-values-pairwise-corr.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Reeza